# Why am I getting "No such file or directory" when I try to execute a binary?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to execute the firefox binary:

```
root@454316a1a89a:/tmp/firefox-portable# ls -la
total 220
drwxr-xr-x  4 jenkins jenkins   4096 Mar 18 21:15 .
drwxrwxrwt  1 root    root      4096 Mar 18 21:48 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jenkins jenkins 202720 Feb 21 17:47 firefox
```

but when I try to execute it, I get the following error message:

```
root@454316a1a89a:/tmp/firefox-portable# ./firefox
bash: ./firefox: No such file or directory
```

Comment: any help please !

Comment: Check whether it's a script. If it is, check whether its interpreter is correctly set on the initial `#!`-line.

Comment: it's a binary file, downloaded from : https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/60.5.2esr/linux-i686/en-US/firefox-60.5.2esr.tar.bz2

Comment: The archive appears to contain a 32-bit binary, which I suspect you are trying to run on a 64-bit system

Comment: you are right :)

Comment: standard ff 64 bit is at https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/

Comment: Please show output of `file ./firefox` and `uname -a`

Answer (score 2):

im trying to executing a 32-bits binary on 64-bit system, thank's @steeldriver

Comment: This does provide an answer: the reason executing the binary produces a “No such file or directory” error is that the user is trying to run a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system.